# JSF: how do you add an empty row to a :dataTable?

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a data table like:

```
<h:dataTable id="box-score-away" value="#{individualAwayBoxScoreQuery.resultList}" var="_bssl">
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Away Team" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Name" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{_bssl.name}" />
    <f:facet name="footer">
      <h:outputText value="&#931;" styleClass="bold" />
    </f:facet>
  </h:column>
  ...
</h:dataTable>
```

When the result list has no elements, the table's tbody becomes empty. Firefox has problems with that and page rendering is really messed up.

How do I add a line to tbody when the result list is empty? (Note, it's not about the condition but rather the components to use and where to put them.)

The row is supposed to be a td with a colspan of 10. I tried a few things without success. Is f:verbatim the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#{individualAwayBoxScoreQuery.resultList}
```

You can handle this in your model. Conditionally return a `List` containing a single empty bean (I guess a `Map` would do too). There are several ways to do this: in the back bean; an EL functions; etc.

*If memory servers, MyFaces does this automatically to generate valid XHTML.*

Comment: Hmm I was looking for a solution that generates a td tag with a colspan of 10. A dummy list element won't work I guess.

Comment: @Kawu - the default table renderer won't do this; I guess you could put a `renderered` attribute on the table and conditionally render the table or a dummy empty verbatim. I guess you could do it with JavaScript too.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and I ended up using dojo to add a `<tr>` to the table body.

For the example above it might look something like below:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){

if(dojo.isMozilla) {
    var bodyElem = dojo.query(".yourTablesStyleClass tbody")[0];

    dojo.create("tr", null, bodyElem, "last");

}  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the empty bean to the class and rendering the column conditionlly helped me to create empty row at the bottom of the table.

```
      add a new boolean to the bean say dummyRow
      then set bean.setName(".")
               bean.setDummyRow(true);
       resultList.add(bean)

    Now in the jsp you need to chang like this
     <h:outputText value="#{_bssl.name}" rendered="{!_bssl.dummyRow}"/>
```

By this I am able to create a empty row at the bottom so that my issue is resolved. My issue was not able to view the bottom most row because of the horizontal scroll bar.